# Is it a good idea to use a hash (sha1) as id for a firestore document?

Tags: firebase, hash, google-cloud-firestore, sha1, bing-api

**My scenario is like follows:**

1. I'm using the BING news api and the return from the api is a list of the following object:

```json
{
    "name": "Eterna Resenha contará com as participações de Neto e Vampeta",
    "url": "https://www.terra.com.br/esportes/lance/eterna-resenha-contara-com-as-participacoes-de-neto-e-vampeta,82e493e511734febfcdfda6fbd22c105xjafr9k2.html",
    "image": {
        "contentUrl": "http://p2.trrsf.com/image/fget/cf/800/450/middle/images.terra.com/2020/05/27/5ece8e302d1fb.jpeg",
        "thumbnail": {
            "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.4E1CF6986982B70A3D6009F435822EF2&pid=News",
            "width": 700,
            "height": 393
        }
    },
    "description": "Durante a quarentena, as lives tomaram conta do país, tentando arrecadar doações para ajudar quem sofre com o coronavírus...",
    "provider": [
        {
            "_type": "Organization",
            "name": "Terra"
        }
    ],
    "datePublished": "2020-05-28T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "category": "Entertainment"
}
```

2. Note that there is no `id` field in this object, so I improvised an id by turning the `datePublished` field to `Date` and used the `getTime` method to return a long and then concatenated with the news language as follows:

```js
const time = new Date(news.datePublished).getTime()
const id = `${language}${time}`

await database.collection(`news`).doc(`${id}`).set(news, { merge: true })
```

3. This solution becomes inefficient when the same news is returned from the BING api with an updated date which causes the object to be duplicated in my firestore database.

**The solution I plan to use**

Transform the news url into a `hash` using the `sha1` algorithm as follows:

```js
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const id = `${CryptoJS.SHA1(news.url)}`

await database.collection(`news`).doc(`${id}`).set(news, { merge: true })
```

The [firestore document creation best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids) guide leaves scope for using ids in this format. But my main concern is with the performance with big id (d40e5b8df6462e138fe617a84ddabae7f78360a6) since I will have thousands of news in at least 5 languages.

**Remeber:** I need to create traceable IDs (based on some object property) because some news can be retrieved from BING news with the same content and the different `datePublished`, then I will need update them.

I would like to know if there are any counter points that make me choose another solution?

Comment: I don't think it's against Firestore patterns to do so. At least, I haven't seen anything in their documentation that warn developers. Firebase allows developers to define their own document ID in both Firestore and RTDB. So, I believe it's safe to use a sha1 (or other hash-related methods). The only thing they say about using your own document identifier methods is to [avoid "hotspot"](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices). But hash-related methods won't create hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firestore's default ID generator function. I am pretty sure "a big ID" won't cause a noticable performance issue, hence why Google is using such a function for generating unique IDs in their databases.

Here's the function I've extracted and been using for my projects for a long while:

```js
        const generateId = function () {
        // Alphanumeric characters
        const chars =
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        let autoId = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            autoId += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
        }
        return autoId;
    };
```

Probability of running into same ID for two documents is virtually impossible with this function, but you can go ahead and also add a timestamp to the result, just to ease your mind.

Comment: Thanks Ogulcan, but I need to create traceable IDs (based on some object property) because some news can be retrieved from BING news with the same content and the different `datePublished`